# TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined - specific bug

Tags: node.js, discord.js, ytdl

My bot uses the /play command, which previously delivered this list to choose the song

[image]

Suddenly gives the error "Cannot read property 'length' of undefined" and I don't understand why if It worked correctly before

[image]

Here I leave the specific part where I suppose the error occurs

```
const videos = await youtube.searchVideos(query, 5).catch(async function() {
      await message.say(
        '> There was a problem searching the video you requested >.<'
      ).then(message.react('❌'));
      return;
    });
    if (videos.length < 5 || !videos) {
      message.say(
        `> I had some trouble finding what you were looking for, please try again or be more specific`
      ).then(message.react('❌'));
      return;
    }
    const videosNameArr = [];
    for (let i = 0; i < videos.length; i++) {
      videosNameArr.push(`${i + 1}: ${videos[i].title}`);
    }
    videosNameArr.push('cancel');
    const embed = new MessageEmbed()
      .setColor('#ffffff')
      .setTitle('Choose a song/video.')
      .addField('Song 1', videosNameArr[0])
      .addField('Song 2', videosNameArr[1])
      .addField('Song 3', videosNameArr[2])
      .addField('Song 4', videosNameArr[3])
      .addField('Song 5', videosNameArr[4])
      .addField('Exit', 'Cancel');
    var songEmbed = await message.channel.send({ embed });
    message.channel
      .awaitMessages(
        function(msg) {
          return (msg.content > 0 && msg.content < 6) || msg.content === 'cancel';
        },
        {
          max: 1,
          time: 60000,
          errors: ['time']
        }
      )
      .then(function(response) {
        const videoIndex = parseInt(response.first().content);
        if (response.first().content === 'cancel') {
          songEmbed.delete().then(message.channel.send("> Song canceled"));;
          return;
        }
```

If someone who knows how to solve it please help me, or if not ask me for the complete code of the command and I will pass it on, thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Ok. So instead of using `const videos = await youtube.searchVideos(query, 5).catch(async function() {`, you should try `await youtube.searchVideos(query, 5).then(videos => {`. or even split this on two lines.

---

Here you got an error because videos is not declared in the function, but outside, so it has no content. A tip to find the error yourself would be to use `console.log()` to check variables and their content, that is very helpful finding the issue.
If what I answered you above doesn't fix the problem, tell me and I'll check this more in detail.

Comment: Hey, it gives me this new error https://imgur.com/4nWSGn7

Comment: That's pretty simple. Your function isn't `async`. Make sure to place the `async` keyword in front of your function declaration (`async function () {...}` or `async () => {...}`)

Comment: @Lioness100 I didn't understand very well, could you do it with my code? please. I tried with ```await youtube.searchVideos(query, 5).catch(async (videos) => {``` but gives me `ReferenceError: videos is not defined`